# password error connecting to mysql database with python 3.3.1

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

i'm a newbie to python, trying to learn some stuff by writing server scripts which connect to our mysql databases and do some stuff. i have python 3.3.1, and mysql 5.0.96 (community). i installed the mysql connector/python, and tried to do a basic connection using the sample code on the mysql dev site. here is my simple python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3


import sys
import mysql.connector

db_config = {
    'user': 'joebloggs',
    'password': 'cleartext_passwd',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'mydb'
}
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ('select usable_name, user_id from user')
cursor.execute(query)
for (usable_name, user_id) in cursor:
    print("{} is the usable name of {d}".format(usable_name, user_id))
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

but i am getting an error connecting to the database

```
"Authentication with old (insecure) passwords "\
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication with old (insecure) passwords is not supported. For more information, lookup Password Hashing in the latest MySQL manual
```

what am i doing wrong? any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports two password encryption schemes, and yours are using the old legacy version. Newer clients refuse to use those as they're pretty trivial to crack.

You need to update your passwords to the new style: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/old-client.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. i found the answer and it was a bit obscure (at least for me!). one of the first things i did prior to posting here at stackoverflow was update the password in the mysql user table to use the new style password. python script still didn't work. then after checking your link i inspected the privileges for that user in phpMyAdmin and it was set to use the new password already, as i expected. hmmmmm. but in the end what i had to do was "flush privileges" to update mysqld with the new info. et voila, python happy! me happy too! thx!